# Pointiness isn't working

Tags: node-editor

I'm using cycles and I was following a tutorial on making a pumpkin but the pointiness didn't work for me. I restarted blender and tried it again with just a monkey and still nothing happened
[image: image of monkey]

Comment: You may be using cycles, but the shading tab (pictured above) uses material preview mode by default which uses a renderer more similar to eevee. Press z in the 3D viewport and select "rendered" from the pie menu to see your model rendered in cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointiness works in a "specific" range. Just move the two slider closer together like this:

[image]

Note: this works only in "rendered" view [image]

Comment: for a complete answer you should include the note from the comment (viewport shading = rendered)

Comment: @Blunder: Thank you! I added that to my answer